# how to receive uuid from postman into tornado application?

Tags: websocket, tornado

I have saved my model in elastic database with uuid, I make a call from Postman using that uuid to my tornado application, the uuid is having my model, how should I receive that in POST method in my requestHandler, below is the code

```
class myHandler(RequestHandler):  
    _thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

    #My data base url
    def initialize(self): 
        self.db = self.settings['db']

    #POST method to receive data and model
    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self, model_id):
        try:
            data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
            yield self.predict(model_id, self.db, data)
        except Exception:
            self.respond('server_error', 500)

    ###here I have predict methods that receive the model_id and pass###
```

The model_id in the post method argument is the uuid I receive from postman

My application call looks like

```
elastic_url = os.environ.get('ELASTICSEARCH_URL', 'localhost:9200')
define('port', default=8888, help='Tornado port to listen on')

def make_app():  
    url = [(r"/uuid/predict", myHandler)]
    return Application(url, db=elastic_url, debug=True, autoreload=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = make_app()
    http_server = HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

From POSTMAN I call the API as

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/9cd68748-a3b5-4bc3-994d-16e921103cb2/predict
```

If I am not having uuid, I simply receive using regex as below

```
url = [(r"/(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/predict", myHandler)
#From POSTMAN I call as
http://127.0.0.1:8888/model_name/predict
```

Comment: The name of this capture group -- `(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)` -- is `id`, but in your handler you're accepting `model_id`. Either change the name of capture group to `model_id` or change the argument name in your methods to `id`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed uuid also used the same (?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) it worked

Comment: Hi, if you've solved your issue, please add an answer to your question and accept your answer so that the question is closed.

Comment: Hi, Yes,as per your previous comment i used the model_id in the url = [(r"/(?P<model_id>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/predict", myHandler) and the regex [a-zA-Z0-9_]+, things worked, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matched the name 'model_id' in url and post function

```
    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self, model_id):
        try:
            data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
            yield self.predict(model_id, self.db, data)
        except Exception:
            self.respond('server_error', 500)
```

and used the url as follows

```
url = [(r"/(?P<model_id>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/predict", myHandler)
#From POSTMAN I call as
http://127.0.0.1:8888/d460e889-6860-4fb4-b040-fee70c96a029.mods/predict
```